# I have a postregsql test container spun up, i would like to insert data after its spun up

Tags: java, spring, testcontainers

I have a postgresql test container spun up in my spring project, all works okay.

```
PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer =
                 new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(POSTGRES_IMAGE))
```

I have a script that i want to run after its running, and it has to be after, as im doing other operations before this.

Does anyone know how i can run this... is there something in the container that i can leverage or do i need to create a connection ie JDBC. Maybe there is something in spring that i can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lifecycle methods, for example overriding:

```
protected void containerIsStarted(InspectContainerResponse containerInfo) {}
```

Would probably help achieve the desired effect.

If you're interested in populating the database schema, creating tables and so on, then you might want to use the Postgres Docker image init dir for scripts ([Initialization scripts chapter in the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)) and copy your scripts there.

So something like this would work:

```
static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer =
    new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:14-alpine")
      .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("schema.sql"), 
                              "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/");
```

And the schema script with be executed when the container is starting and when the container is started and the control flow is back in your tests -- the schema will be there.